# Use .LESS rather then compiling to .css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compilation, less

Just wondering what are the advantages of compiling .less in to .css with compilers such as Crunch or Prepros rather than including the .less file directly? Does .less rely on less.js library and the .css could be a standalone? I am using it for Twitter Bootstrap 3.

Comment: You *can't* use the Less file directly. That's the advantage of CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage is that the site is available and ready for browsers that have javascript disabled or have no support for it.

There are also server-side pre-request compilers that take the manual compilation step out of the process but don't depend on javascript in the browser. This makes for a best-of-both-worlds solution.

One such example is the [Rails asset-pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing). All of the benefits, none of the weaknesses. :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a .less file would require the less.js library. I would be surprised if there are any browsers who understand .less natively. So the advantage of compiling it to CSS is clear: less overhead (no less.js dependency) and faster parsing.

Comment: As far as I understand Bootstrap 3 uses bootstrap.less which calls variables.less which calls the rest of the .less files required. I have tried compiling bootstrap.less to .css file but it doesn't work if less.js library is not added as well? I thought wouldn't need the less.js library if compiling to .css? In my case, I have made a change to the gutter width.